# How to read contents of scipy hierarchy cluster

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I have the following code with which I am clustering hierarchically. My data object is an array of similarity distances I calculated earlier. I think I am executing the clustering properly. I thought I could just get the leaves of the Cluster, but when I compare that to the original input I get a mismatch.

I have two questions here:

Why is there a mismatch between the leaves of my cluster and my actual input data?

How can I extract the original data from a cluster by either the linkage matrix or clusternodes?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch

def list_difference(list1, list2):
    return [value for value in list1 if value not in list2]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # example data for this questions purpose.
    data = [10, 11, 29, 288, 16]

    X = np.array([[i] for i in data])
    linkage_matrix = sch.average(X)
    rootnode, nodelist = sch.to_tree(linkage_matrix, rd=True)

    leaves = sch.leaves_list(linkage_matrix)
    print(list_difference(leaves, data))
```

I want to retrieve the original data points per cluster.

Comment: Please, fix your code

Comment: I Updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data

```
data = [10, 11, 29, 288, 16]
```

the result is compatible with the dendrogram

```
sch.dendrogram(linkage_matrix);
```

[image]

Analyzing `linkage_matrix` we can confirm

```
print(linkage_matrix)

array([[  0.        ,   1.        ,   1.        ,   2.        ],
       [  4.        ,   5.        ,   5.5       ,   3.        ],
       [  2.        ,   6.        ,  16.66666667,   4.        ],
       [  3.        ,   7.        , 271.5       ,   5.        ]])
```

Row by row we have

- element 0 and element 1, with distance 1 in a cluster that has got 2 elements (this cluster will be called 5)
- element 4 with clustered elements 5 (the previous), with distance 5.5 and 3 elements (this cluster will be called 6)
- element 2 with clustered elements 6 (the previous), with distance 16.667 and 4 elements (this cluster will be called 7)
- element 3 with clustered elements 7 (the previous), with distance 271.5 and 5 elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It makes a lot of sense now!! So how can you deduce that the first cluster will be called 5 with only the linkage matrix as input data?

Comment: YVW. The 1st cluster will be called 5 (in this case) because you have 5 elements {0,1,2,3,4}. So the "next available name" is 5. The 2nd cluster will be called 6 and so on, till pth cluster. So, say you got n elements, the pth clusters will be called (n-1)+p, with p=[1,2,...]. With the linkage matrix only, you can see that 5 is a cluster name (even if you don't know the number of elements) because it contains more than two elements.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "since the cluster IT HAS BEEN CLUSTERED IN has got more than 2 elements"